# Re-recording with AVAudioRecorder

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudiorecorder

I can record with the setup below - it works first time, but then when I try again the file is always 8192 bytes, i.e. not a correct recording.

```
-(void) startRecording
{

    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 11025.0f],                     AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC],           AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],                              AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityLow],              AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                          nil];

    NSString *filenameBasedOnTime = [[NSDate date] description];

    if (_recordedFileURL) _recordedFileURL = nil;

   _recordedFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:filenameBasedOnTime]];

   NSError* error;

   if (_audioRecorder) _audioRecorder = nil;

   _audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:_recordedFileURL settings:settings error:&error];
   _audioRecorder.delegate = self;

   if (error)
   {    
     return;
   }

   [_audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
   _audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
   [_audioRecorder record];
}

-(void) stopRecord
{
   [_audioRecorder stop];
}

- (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    [self saveRecording];
}

-(void) saveRecording
{   
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_recordedFileURL.relativeString]];

    NSLog(@"Recording data size = %i", [data length]);
}
```

It is called inside a UIPopoverController if that helps...

Comment: it might be useful to log what any possible "`error`" might be instead of simply returning.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann It does, just took it out for the sake of brevity.

Comment: The setup certainly looks good.  What does the "`stopRecording`" method look like?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann See my answer Michael

Answer (score 1):

Since found out that the problem was I was missing

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:NULL];
```

From here [iPhone SDK: AVAudioRecorder will not record after calling [AVPlayer play]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345337/iphone-sdk-avaudiorecorder-will-not-record-after-calling-avplayer-play)